# rails3-jquery-autocomplete not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am getting the following error in the java script consule (chrome)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'   autocomplete-rails.js
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After ading these three rows below the error message went away. Now when i enter values in the field nothing happens.

<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css', :media => 'stylesheet' %>

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery UI with Autocomplete support.

1. Go to http://jqueryui.com/download
2. Deselect all, then select "Autocomplete".
3. Download the ZIP file, extract it and copy the minified file from the `js/` folder, to `app/assets/javascripts/` in your Rails 3 app (this will let it show up on every page in your app, but you can optimize this later).
4. Reload your app in the browser.

The error should now have gone away!